# Maven Properties - Git Bash Shell on Windows Prompt Is Not UTF-8

Tags: bash, git, maven

Using Maven 3.5.3 in Windows 10 cmd window from a Git v2.24.0 Bash shell.

I've been using Maven on my Windows 10 workstation for over five years. A drive failed, so I did a fresh install of the OS, but replaced my apps from backup. I can't figure out how to get the command prompt from maven to display correctly. I've tried setting pom.xml properties, like this:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
```

But it's not helping.

Here's a screen shot:
[image]

Thanks for helping!
Bob

Comment: In the screen shoot your project is using the configured `UTF-8`, and `mvn -v` is showing the platform's encoding.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The solution was to update maven to v3.6.3. I was planning to leave all my apps at the versions that worked with my previous Win10 install because I was focused on development, and not wanting to go through the pain of app updates. In this case, no issues came up with the upgrade.

Comment: You should check your projects cause the WARNING at the beginning shows there is something wrong usage of `LATEST` or `RELEASE`...You should check if you have turned on ANSI support in the console?

Comment: I'm OK with the maven errors at this point. The question I wanted solved was the encoding.Maven bash shell encodings are fine now.